# i want the if statement to keep giving back the prompt("wat is uw naam?") while the input value is null otherwise the confirm

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Pagina geladen')
    if (confirm) {
        let naam = prompt("Wat is uw naam?")
        let naam2 = prompt("Uw naam is " + naam + " is dit correct? ")
        let naam3 = document.write("Welkom " + naam + " een fijne dag gewenst! ")
    }
    while (naam == null || 'null' || "") {
        prompt("Wat is uw naam?")
    }

</script>
```

i tried above, but even if i click on cancel it gives back the null value on the html instead of keep asking the prompt("Wat is uw naam?") with the while loop.

The confirm works, only the while loop with null doesn't work.

Comment: The code that gets repeated by a loop is *inside the loop body*. So, if you want `prompt("Wat is uw naam?")` (or the whole `if` or whatever code) to be repeated, it should be inside the `{ }` that belong to the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the value AND set the confirmation in the loop.
If they cancel the confirmation, you need to clear the name for the inner loop

The test is also wrong. You need to repeat the variable name

`while (naam === null || naam === "") {` but we can shorten that to `while (!naam)` where `!` is the NOT operator.

I also simplified the strings using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
alert('Pagina geladen');
let confirmedName = false;
let naam = prompt("Wat is uw naam?");

while (!confirmedName) {
  while (!naam) { // This checks for both null and empty string
    naam = prompt("Wat is uw naam?");
  }
  confirmedName = confirm(`Uw naam is ${naam}, is dit correct?`);
  if (!confirmedName) naam = ""; // they changed their mind
}

document.write(`Welkom ${naam}, een fijne dag gewenst!`);
```

It is not recommended to use document.write. Instead add the string to an element on the page. I also put the prompt into a reusable function.

```js
console.log('Pagina geladen');
let confirmedName = false;
let naam; // placeholder
const getName = () => prompt('Wat is uw naam?'); // saves repeating the prompt later

while (!confirmedName) {
  while (!(naam = getName())) { // This checks for both null and empty string
    // Loop continues until a non-falsy name is entered
  }
  confirmedName = confirm(`Uw naam is ${naam}, is dit correct?`);
  if (!confirmedName) naam = ""; // they changed their mind
}

document.getElementById('goedendag').textContent = `Welkom ${naam}, een fijne dag gewenst!`;
```

```html
<h1 id="goedendag"></h1>
```

Comment: thanks for everything! appreciate it ;)